How can I check if the backend admin has logged in on the frontend in Magento 2?
How to check from the frontend whether the admin has logged in at the backend in Magento 2?
I want to develop a module in Magento 2.
If the admin has logged in to the backend, I want the SKU field in the frontend to be visible.
Can someone help me find where I am making a mistake?
I have tried this but, it doesn't work.
<?php

namespace Ensa\SwatchSku\Helper;

use Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session as AuthSession;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $authSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        AuthSession                           $authSession
    )
    {
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function isAdminLoggedIn()
    {
        return $this->authSession->isLoggedIn();
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" template="Ensa_SwatchSku::product/view.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>

<?php
/** @var \Ensa\SwatchSku\Helper\Data $helper */
$helper = $this->helper('Ensa\SwatchSku\Helper\Data');
if ($helper->isAdminLoggedIn()):
    echo "Admin Logged IN";
else:
    echo "There is no logged-in admin";
endif;
?>

